# How do I create an boolean array and check if all boolean are true and then execute smth

Tags: java, boolean

I have a boolean Array. I want to check if all of this booleans are true.

How can I print a message, if all of them are true?

```
public static boolean[] tubes = new boolean[9];
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are several ways this could be implemented.

Comment: I tried it with an for loop. An then checked it with if(Tubes[i] == true) System.out.println("All of them are true"); But this check every boolean and outputs that 9 times. I only want 1 output which says that all of them are true. I hope you understand sry for my english.

Comment: i already checked this. but no solution for my problem :/

Comment: @TechnikFabrik The for loop should store the *aggregation* of values (and can break as soon as an unmatching value is found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop elements and store its result in a variable as shown below:-

```java
boolean isTrue = false;
for (boolean bool : tubes) {
    isTrue = bool;
    if (!isTrue) {
       break;
    }
}

if (isTrue) {
  // print...
}
```

Another solution

```java
boolean isTrue = true;
for (boolean bool : tubes) {
    isTrue &= bool;
}

if (isTrue) {
  // print...
}
```

Comment: You could replace the loop body with `if (!(isTrue = bool)) break;`: this stops as soon as a false is found.

Comment: @AndyTurner Done

Comment: @MontaserSobaih I didn't say you should remove your version. It is arguably less readable. I might present both as options (or even `isTrue = bool; if (!isTrue) break;` instead of the version with the inline assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
    public boolean checkFunction(boolean[] Tubes) {
    //boolean[] Tubes = new boolean[9];
    boolean et = true; // by default, every member of the array is true

    for(int i=0; i < 9;i++) {
        if (Tubes[i] == false) { // if i find a false item then its false
            System.out.println("This is false: " + Tubes[i]);
            et = false;
        }
    }
    return et;
}
```